# Debug log4j Configuration in a spring boot webapplication

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, log4j

I am developing a multimodule webapp with spring boot. My webapplication always takes the log4j config from the dependend submodule, which is not desired. Is there a way to show debug info, which logback or log4j file is used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude default by adding these to pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```