# Use application.yml to configure logging of embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a number of questions here (and I'm new to Spring Boot).

Our project's existing codebase uses YAML but no `.properties` file that I can see anywhere. My reading of usual Spring Boot tutorial uses `.properties` file.

(1) Is it possible to use `application.yml` as replacement for `application.properties`?

(2) Where is the default directory/file where the Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat server dumps its logs?

I need to modify the configuration such that we have custom directory to dump embedded Tomcat server logs. According to [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html), it should be

```
server.tomcat.basedir=my-tomcat
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
```

That is how it's done if using `application.properties` way.

(3) Assuming YAML can replace the `.properties` file entirely, how can I do the above configuration in YAML? Do I need to edit something in the Java source files in order for the configuration in YAML to take effect (that is Tomcat logs going into specific directory that I want)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Completely
2. Spring boot doesn't log to a file by default (as far I know).

Whether you use yaml or properties file, spring boot uses this configuration to bootstrap the application. The below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312851/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-logs)

```
# LOGGING
logging.config= # Location of the logging configuration file. For instance `classpath:logback.xml` for Logback
logging.exception-conversion-word=%wEx # Conversion word used when logging exceptions.
logging.file= # Log file name. For instance `myapp.log`
logging.level.*= # Log levels severity mapping. For instance `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`
logging.path= # Location of the log file. For instance `/var/log`
logging.pattern.console= # Appender pattern for output to the console. Only supported with the default logback setup.
logging.pattern.file= # Appender pattern for output to the file. Only supported with the default logback setup.
logging.pattern.level= # Appender pattern for log level (default %5p). Only supported with the default logback setup.
logging.register-shutdown-hook=false # Register a shutdown hook for the logging system when it is initialized.

server.tomcat.accept-count= # Maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use.
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=true # Buffer output such that it is only flushed periodically.
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=logs # Directory in which log files are created. Can be relative to the tomcat base dir or absolute.
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=false # Enable access log.
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd # Date format to place in log file name.
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=common # Format pattern for access logs.
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log # Log file name prefix.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rename-on-rotate=false # Defer inclusion of the date stamp in the file name until rotate time.
server.tomcat.accesslog.request-attributes-enabled=false # Set request attributes for IP address, Hostname, protocol and port used for the request.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true # Enable access log rotation.
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log # Log file name suffix.
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns= # Comma-separated list of additional patterns that match jars to ignore for TLD scanning.
server.tomcat.background-processor-delay=30 # Delay in seconds between the invocation of backgroundProcess methods.
server.tomcat.basedir= # Tomcat base directory. If not specified a temporary directory will be used.
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=10\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        192\\.168\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        127\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.1[6-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.2[0-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
        172\\.3[0-1]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3} # regular expression matching trusted IP addresses.
server.tomcat.max-connections= # Maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=0 # Maximum size in bytes of the HTTP post content.
server.tomcat.max-threads=0 # Maximum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=0 # Minimum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.port-header=X-Forwarded-Port # Name of the HTTP header used to override the original port value.
server.tomcat.protocol-header= # Header that holds the incoming protocol, usually named "X-Forwarded-Proto".
server.tomcat.protocol-header-https-value=https # Value of the protocol header that indicates that the incoming request uses SSL.
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root= # Whether requests to the context root should be redirected by appending a / to the path.
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header= # Name of the http header from which the remote ip is extracted. For instance `X-FORWARDED-FOR`
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8 # Character encoding to use to decode the URI.
```

3. Yes. You can change these to YML. All you need is to replace properties file with yml file. You could even have both in your workspace (spring looks at both application.properties and application.yml)
   You can manually do the conversion or even with [plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8000-properties-to-yaml-converter).

A simple line like

`logging.level.netpl.com = DEBUG`

changes to

```
logging:
  level:
    netpl.com: DEBUG
```