# How to enable Tomcat Logs in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, log4j2

When we use external tomcat to deploy our Spring MVC application, there are certain log files which get printed in the logs folder, i.e., host-manager.log, localhost.log, manager.log, etc.
I needed to enable the generation of these logs in my Spring Boot Application too. How can we do that?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312851/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-logs

Comment: @Debanjan Thanks for your reply. I have added the following property in the application, but I think all the logs are getting printed on console only. I needed to print them in different files. logging.level.org.apache=TRACE

Answer (score 1):

Please check spring docs for logging in file-output: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.file-output

Or alternatively you can use `logback-spring.xml` to achieve this.

Sample `logback-spring.xml` which prints logs in the console and file and it daily rollovers the file or if it reaches 10MB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<property name="LOGS" value="./logs"/> <!-- the folder where you want your log files to be -->

<appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10MBs -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</root>
```

More about how to config logback: https://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html