# How to prevent apache server to be hitting twice on a java get request

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc

I'm using an `apache tomcat server`, on doing a project all my **get request methods are hitting twice** without initiating the call manually. If i call a method, on its return the method is being called again automatically. I have tried many ways but it doesn't helps me. This project is a same copy of another working project, however the old project is working fine.

I have tried these following answers, but this couldn't solve my problem

1. https://www.niceonecode.com/Question/20307/MVC-Controller-Action-Gets-Called-Multiple-Times
2. [Spring controller method called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325529/spring-controller-method-called-twice/36679031#36679031)

I have also verified if any of my scripts is initiating the second call, but there is no scripts like that. 
Can anyone helps me out?

Sample code of my method

`@RequestMapping(value = "/method/test/{id}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getTestMethod(@PathVariable int id, @PathVariable String name, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RedirectAttributes ra)
    {
      System.out.println("success");
      return "success";
    }`

Comment: are you sure it's calling GET, not OPTIONS then GET? - assuming "scripts" means javascript in a HTML page

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for your valuable time. I have updated my question with example of the java method i'm using. It s page load and not an ajax call through script.

Comment: Oh, right, so there's no javascript at all - no ... that's the server, right? so the client is making the two calls, so what is the client getting as a response in the two calls it makes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Then I have changed `href="Favicon.ico"` to empty in my `index.html` file. Then it worked. Change it to `href=""`.